# Playing audio via phonegap and cordova for Android

Tags: android, html, cordova

I've been messing around with programming a test app for android and I've come across a issue playing a audio file. My problem lies with as soon as the page loads the audio file plays when it's not meant to and doesn't play via a button click

I'm using the example for cordova to get the audio to play but I can't work out why the audio plays straight away

Thanks

Script

```
script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            playAudio("/android_asset/www/audio/audio.mp3");
        }

        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;
    function playAudio(src) {
            if (my_media == null) {
                // Create Media object from src
                my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
            } // else play current audio
            // Play audio
            my_media.play();

            // Update my_media position every second
            if (mediaTimer == null) {
                mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                    // get my_media position
                    my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                        // success callback
                        function(position) {
                            if (position > -1) {
                                setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                            }
                        },
                        // error callback
                        function(e) {
                            console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                            setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                        }
                    );
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

</script>
```

HTML button click

```
<a class="button" onclick="playaudio('/android_asset/www/audio/audio.mp3')";>Play that audio!</a>
```

Comment: You are executing playaudio method onDeviceReady, causing playing of sound when page loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `onDeviceReady()` is listener callback for `addEventListener`.

So whenever this listener instantiate your `onDeviceReady()` method will be called automatically.

And from that method you are calling `playAudio()` method, that's why your audio start playing automatically.

Remove this `playAudio()` method call from the `onDeviceReady()` callback function.

**EDIT:**

change this

```
<a class="button" onclick="playaudio('/android_asset/www/audio/audio.mp3')";>Play that audio!</a>
```

with,

```
<a class="button" onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/audio/audio.mp3');">Play that audio!</a>
```

Comment: hi - I've removed it and now the audio doesn't play at all

Comment: Thanks for the reply - changed the code but still not working

Comment: @Grimlockz check have you correctly spelled `playAudio` from button click and also put alert in the `playAudio` to check methos is called or not?

Comment: I'ved amended the code but still not working. It must not being getting called

Comment: @Grimlockz I just edited whole button click code please try with that

Comment: Sorry I can't see what you have changed on the button code? Also the onDeviceReady function now is blank is this correct

Comment: thanks for all your help, what have you changed on the button?

Comment: @Grimlockz actually I placed ";" inside which is right place. And with correct "playAudio" method name. Which intially you have written false like "playaudio".

Comment: ahh thank you let me try that and should the onDeviceReady function just been blank now?

Comment: @Grimlockz yes `onDeviceReady ` is fine with the blank.